# How to clear Textbox if case not found?

Tags: excel, barcode, barcode-scanner, vba

I scan a barcode into an ActiveX textbox. It selects the relevant case and performs the calculation/event depending on the barcode. Every code is connected to an event.

One out of 100+ scans is not correctly decoded to the computer. As such, it does not match a case and does not make the textbox value "". It then appends to every other scan entering into the textbox. Aka "15 - FT - R" might scan in as "15 - FT -R".

I need the code to recognize this as a non case and delete it.

Since the barcode scans each character one at a time, nothing is equal to a case until the barcode value has completely entered the textbox.

Is there any way to tell if the barcode info is done being scanned?

My biggest challenge is how to stop the rest of the text from entering the box once it does not match a case.
My next biggest challenge is setting variables.

```vb
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, v, e, f, g, k, i4
    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    v = TextBox1.Value

    e = 0
    f = 0
    g = 0
    k = 0
    i4 = 0

    Select Case v
            
    Case "15 - FT - R": f = 5
    e = 11
    k = 2
    g = "15 - FT - R"

    Case "150 - FT - C": f = 30
    e = 11
    k = 2
    g = "150 - FT - C"
 
    Case "R Waste": f = 4
    e = 9
    k = 2
    g = "R Waste"

    Case "C Waste": f = 4
    e = 10
    k = 2
    g = "C Waste"

    Case "Accident - 4": k = 5

        'other cases here....

    End Select


    'e = Sets the column reference for taking 1 master roll out
    'f = Sets the row reference for taking 1 master roll out
    'g = name of the item being used for the time stamp
    'k = Case Selection
    'i4 = Count for Cutting Station 1 timestamp, row reference
    
    If k = 2 Then
    'Coating Station
    
        'accidental scan references for coating
        ws.Cells(4, 4) = f
        ws.Cells(5, 4) = e

        ws.Cells(f, e) = ws.Cells(f, e) + 1
        'adds master roll
        
        i4 = ws.Cells(4, 30)
        'count function
        
        Cells(i4, 25).Value = Format(Now, "mm/dd/yyyy AM/PM h:mm:ss")
        Cells(i4, 26).Value = g
        'formatting timestamp
    
        TextBox1.Activate
        TextBox1.Value = ""
     
    'e = Sets the column reference for taking 1 master roll out
    'f = Sets the row reference for taking 1 master roll out
    'k = Case Selection
    'i4 = Count for Cutting Station 1 timestamp, row reference
    
    ElseIf k = 5 Then
        'Accidental scan
          
        f = ws.Cells(4, 4)
        e = ws.Cells(5, 4)
        
        ws.Cells(f, e) = ws.Cells(f, e) - 1
        
        i4 = ws.Cells(4, 30)
        'count function
        
        Cells(i4, 25).Value = Format(Now, "mm/dd/yyyy AM/PM h:mm:ss")
        Cells(i4, 26).Value = "Accident"
        'formatting timestamp
        
        TextBox1.Activate
        TextBox1.Value = ""
   
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Are all the barcodes the same length?

Comment: Hey Com, no they are not. I tried refreshing the application upon conclusion of each entry of a character with no avail also. I also tried smaller barcodes such as 1a1 instead of 15 - FT - R

Comment: Wait, so you're actually printing the barcodes too?

Comment: We have barcode software and a printer. yes, I am and do make and print.

Comment: This is much, much easier if all of the barcodes are the same length or end with some sort of "end of code" marker.

Comment: I can either make them all the same size or add an end code. Although, just because there is an end code may not fix the issue because a missing character does not stop the end code from being say 001 and the code being 15 - FT -R001. I think the same thing would happen with the Length. It doesn't stop a wrong code from occurring, nor eliminate the additional characters from continuing into the box even if I set a Max Length then make value "".

Comment: If your barcode scanner using a keyboard driver? If so, you should be able to encode a tab as the end code.  Then you can just test the whole string on the exit event (and set focus back after you clear it or whatever else you need to do).

Comment: That sounds promising. I can program the scanner to tab / enter upon finishing the scan. It doesnt leave the textbox though, it stays inside. Could you write a brief piece of code for an explanation?

Comment: Is there something after the textbox in the form's tab order?

Comment: Its not in a form, its an ActiveX textbox embedded into Sheet1 of a workbook. I set the enterkey behavior as true, but it functions as before. I guess i could copy all of my code into a form and have it select the next TB within. Then refocus then Tb2 back to TB1 and "" it out? I am not sure how to do it, but I can try to write a Private sub for it?

Answer (score 0):

1. Set TextBox properties:

   ```
   EnterKeyBehavior   TRUE
   Multiline          TRUE
   ```
2. Use this in your VBA _Change call back:

   ```
       If Not Right(Me.Scan.Value, 1) = vbLf Then Exit Sub
   ```

In essence, we're now just looking for the LF character after enabling the multiline capability of the textbox.